# Expo AV Video Component — Loop Part of Video

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo, expo-av

Can I loop the last X seconds of a Video using Expo AV's Video component? For example, say I have a 15s video. I want it to play out fully, but then loop starting at 5s.

I supposed I could achieve the same effect by splitting the video into two videos and then looping the second video only. However, I tried this and had a lag between playing the first and second videos. Let me know if you have ideas!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve this, you will use only one Video component and override the default looping by giving your Video component a callback function to create an artificial loop by using `playFromPositionAsync`.

1. Create a reference to the video that will play

   ```
   let video : Video | null; //add type if using typescript
   ```
2. Create the video component and give a playback function .

   ```
   <Video 
   ref={(r) => {video = r}} //set the video reference  
   source={{uri: uri}}
   isLooping={false} 
   useNativeControls={false} //to not use native play pause... buttons
   shouldPlay //if you want your video to play automatically the first time
   progressUpdateIntervalMillis={100} //the playback update function below will fire every 100ms
   onPlaybackStatusUpdate={_onPlaybackStatusUpdate} />
   ```
3. Define the playback function

   ```
    const _onPlaybackStatusUpdate = (status: AVPlaybackStatus)=>{
     if (status.isLoaded){ //video is loaded without error
       if (status.didJustFinish){ //fired only once when video ends
         video?.playFromPositionAsync(10000, { toleranceMillisBefore: 0, toleranceMillisAfter: 0 }); //start at 10sec with 0 tolerance (starts exactly at 10sec)
        }
      }
    }
   ```

What happens here is your playing your video from 10 sec whenever the end of the video is reached. Note that `didJustFinish` only fires once but you should get frequent updates to check if the playback has in fact ended, hence `progressUpdateIntervalMillis`. Without this, the finish event will be false in the beginning of the video and the loop won't start.